# is it possible to do text pre-processing within query SPARQL?

Tags: java, text, sparql, rdf, preprocessor

I have a problem to search a long text which using natural language but i should process it using SPARQL too because i want return all values from my RDF. So the example is:

```
String query = "SELECT ?x ?z " +
           "WHERE { " +
           "?x rdfs:label ?z  ." +
          "FILTER CONTAINS (LCASE(str(?z)), LCASE('the apple is red')) ."+
           " }";
```

so it should give the result **"apple"** (a keyword) and it can refers to **"fruit"** class in my RDF.

Can someone advise me how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: what is the question now? I mean, what is not working?

Comment: @UninformedUser i mean, how can we pre-processing the text in the ' ' like the example above

Comment: The requirement sounds more like a text search. Most SPARQL engines provide a text search capability (Apache Jena : https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html). The text search finds the ?x and then additional information can be pulled from the RDF.

Comment: *"how can we pre-processing the text in the"* - not sure what you mean by pre-processing, but it obviously happens **before** executing the SPARQL query. So, not sure what exactly you're asking. SPARQL with its standard functions does just what it does, matching the data by contains, regex or equality checks. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: As Andy pointed out, some triple stores to supported more sophisticated fulltext search feature from Information Retrieval. But even those are limited, if you hope to find "fruit" by "apple" you need even more knowledge like WordNet etc. - all this is still ongoing research, obviously homonymy, synonomy, meronymy, polysemie, etc. have to be considered. This is NLP. If you just want to tag text by entities in a knowledge base, you should also consider existing work and check SOTA insted of reinventing the wheel. just my two cents ...